# Find included range from a range given excluded range in python

Tags: python

I have a range say (0,1000).
My another input will be excluded range [(200,400), (600,800)].
I need as output included range [(0,199), (401,599), (801,1000)].

How do I implement this in python?

Comment: Do you mean a `tuple` or a `range`? Can you show some code to indicate what you have tried?

Comment: Personally I don't vote up these type of questions because it doesn't show any particular effort on the part of the OP.

Comment: @achampion You can vote to close it as being too broad, or suchlike.

Answer (score 2):

You can [chain iterables](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) together:

```
from itertools import chain

for i in chain(range(1,200), range(401, 600), range(801, 1001)):
    # etc
```

Also, if you've been given the range and can only iterate over it once, you can use [**`tee`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) and [**`islice`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
def excluded(sequence):
    first, second, third = tee(sequence, 3)
    yield from chain(islice(first, 1, 200),
                     islice(second, 401, 600),
                     islice(third, 801, 1001))

for i in excluded(range(0, 1000)):
    # etc.
```

Comment: Does this include the endpoints?

Comment: Misses 1000, but otherwise meets the expected output, but unclear if it addresses the OP question given it asks for exclusion from a range.

Comment: @achampion the question is contradictory as it says `range(0, 1000)`.

Comment: True, the output includes 1000 but not 0, inverse to the python range. Could argue you missed 0 then :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you wanted tuples, this

```
def exclude_ranges(to, exc):
    cur = 0
    res = []
    for ef, et in exc:
        res.append((cur, ef-1))
        cur = et + 1
    res.append((cur, to))
    return res

exc = [(200, 400), (600, 800)]
ranges = exclude_ranges(1000, exc)
print ranges
```

produces

```
[(0, 199), (401, 599), (801, 1000)]
```

As suggested below, it may be worth it to make it a generator:

```
def exclude_ranges(to, exc):
    cur = 0
    res = []
    for ef, et in exc:
        yield cur, ef-1
        cur = et + 1
    yield cur, to

exc = [(200, 400), (600, 800)]
ranges = exclude_ranges(1000, exc)
print list(ranges) # or for i in ranges: print i
```

Comment: If you use  `yield cur, ef-1` and `yield (cur, to)` you can do both nicely

Comment: yes, of course you can make it a generator

Answer (score 0):

```
exclude_ranges = [range(200, 400), range(600, 800)]
# convert the ranges to sets for quick lookup
exclude_ranges = [set(er) for er in exclude_ranges]

for x in range(1000):
    if any(x in er for er in exclude_ranges):
        # within exclude range, skip it
        continue
    # x is within allowed range
```